# Modal seque UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make add photo button to my project, exactly like instagram add photo button (or like Control Center when show) which that do modal seque and do presentViewController to another UIViewController then in that UIViewController make a rect(0,0,320,200) with black background and alpha 0.5, and another rect (0,200,320,280) with button, etc. I make that is simple. But when modal seque called alpha be 1 and not transparent. it's black. How can I solve this problem.

A simple example like **Control Center in iOS** could be helpful.

Here is the picture of addPhoto button

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post some code. But right off the bat, when you present another ViewController, the viewcontroller behind it will not be visible.  Meaning you can't look through one viewController and see the next viewController.  To achieve what you have in the picture, the top view has to be added as a subview to the current viewController.  Or if you really want separate viewControllers, you can take a screenshot of the previous viewController and add it as a background to the second viewController.  Hope this helps.